# Quarkus Kafka: How to configure the number of retry attempts if we are not able to connect to the Kafka Broker?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I am working on a Quarkus application and intend to use Kafka to receive messages, however I want to stop the application if the application is not able to reach Kafka broker after retrying for a certain number of times. The default configuration is to try infinite number of times to reconnect. In the documentation at [Smallrye Reactive Messaging Kafka](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/2.5/kafka/kafka.html#kafka-installation), it says we can use `kafka.retry-attempts` or `mp.messaging.incoming.[channel-name].retry-attempts` to configure the number of retries. I have tried both but the application still goes on retring.

Have someone faced a similar issue or can someone help me with the resolution?

Comment: Have created an issue with Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13664